# How to Make CMDIChildWnd as Dockable in MFC?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I want to Make CMDIChildWnd as Dockable.... My Code which Create Window Frame While click on ribbon Button and I want Docking all window in tabbed format, when i place Drag My Frame is show Docking Manager Format[DT_SMART]...

This Code is Button Click event create multiple Frame....

```
    pDocTemplate_New1 = new CMultiDocTemplate ( IDR_RiboonCFormViewTYPE, 
                RUNTIME_CLASS(CRiboonCFormViewTestDoc),
                RUNTIME_CLASS(CChildFrame), // custom MDI child frame
                RUNTIME_CLASS(CDepartement));
    AfxGetApp () -> AddDocTemplate (pDocTemplate_New1); 

    // Create a new child window 
    CMDIChildWnd * pMDIActive = MDIGetActive (); // get the pointer of the currently active child window 
    //CDocument * pDoc = (CDocument *) pMDIActive-> GetActiveDocument (); // get the document pointer 
    CMDIChildWnd * pNewFrame = (CMDIChildWnd *) (pDocTemplate_New1 -> CreateNewFrame (NULL, NULL));
    pNewFrame->EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);
    EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);
    // Create a new frame window 
    if (pNewFrame == NULL) 
    { 
        AfxMessageBox("new window can not be established ", MB_OK, 0); 
    } 
    pDocTemplate_New1 -> InitialUpdateFrame (pNewFrame, NULL); // display window 
    MDITile (MDITILE_HORIZONTAL); // tile multiple windows
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a dockable pane first, To create a dockable pane you must first derive from the `CMDIFrameWndEx`.
2. Add that pane member in `CMainFrame`
3. Styles that matter, `CBRS_FLOAT_MULTI` make the dockable pane float as a unit when attached to a tab.
   An alignment style like `CBRS_LEFT` gives the pane the initial alignment.
4. Tabbed pane is a concept of docking panes to each other to form a regular tab control with individual panes inside.
   Use `AttachToTabWnd`() to add your pane

Comment: Thanks for your Reply,                                             Actually I am new in MFC, So will you please explain How to create that, I am not getting what you are saying. The Above code is creating Multiple MDIChild Frame, but is not dockable in one another.                                                           What changes i have to do in above code to make it Work as Dockable as well as Create multiple Frame on button click

Comment: I thought I have explained enough, I don't have any code sample with me, Google it! But even before you do that, I suggest you study simple MFC SDI applications first.